# Placing Radiobuttons in next line (according to text size) in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, radio-button, radio-group

In Android:

I have 4 radio buttons in a radio group and I want to place them horizontally. But if length of any `RadioButton`'s text increases, automatically other radio buttons shift to next line. Unfortunately, they get disappeared and go out of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"


        />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"

        />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"

        />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"

       />


 </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: give height of radio group is wrap content and width match parent...

Comment: @Aashvi-doing this compresses my text.I dont want that.

Comment: I have removed layout_weight="1" --it compresses the text.

Answer (score 0):

Use scroll view and try this

```
             <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rdoAnswerzGroup"
                style="@style/home_nav_form_input_style"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <widget.TypefaceRadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/qoption1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="UG"
                    android:textColor="@color/theme_gray_level1"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/form_input_font_size"
                    app:radioButtonTypeface="Roboto-Light"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp" />

                <widget.TypefaceRadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/qoption2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:text="UG"
                    android:textColor="@color/theme_gray_level1"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/form_input_font_size"
                    app:radioButtonTypeface="Roboto-Light" />

                <widget.TypefaceRadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/qoption3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:text="UG"
                    android:textColor="@color/theme_gray_level1"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/form_input_font_size"
                    app:radioButtonTypeface="Roboto-Light" />

                <widget.TypefaceRadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/qoption4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left|top"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:text="UG dfsdfs dfsdf d dfsdfsdf \n dfsdfsdf"
                    android:textColor="@color/theme_gray_level1"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/form_input_font_size"
                    app:radioButtonTypeface="Roboto-Light" />
            </RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to give equal width

```
<RadioGroup
android:id="@+id/yourRadioGroup"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio0ne"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="FirstButton" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioTwo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SecondButton" />
```

Comment: If the text of my first radiobutton is long,then i want other three radiobuttons to shift to next line